# Why jQuery data table does not export date correctly when month is two digit in Laravel when export as EXCEL file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to get export data as an `EXCEL` file exactly as shown in the view, it works, but did not export date correctly, I tried like below:

```
 $('#get_hourly_report').click(function () {

        var id = $('#teacher').val();
        var first_date = $('#jalali-datepicker3').val();
        var second_date = $('#jalali-datepicker4').val();
        $(".h_report_icon").addClass('fa fa-spinner fa-spin');
        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: "attendance/getTeacherAttendanceReport/",
            data: {
                'id': id,
                'f_date': first_date,
                's_date': second_date
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YYYY');
                table = $('#example2').DataTable({

                    destroy: true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    bFilter: false,
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            extend: 'excelHtml5',
                            footer: true,
                            customize: (xlsx, config, dataTable) => {
                                let sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                                let footerIndex = $('sheetData row', sheet).length;
                                let $footerRows = $('tr', dataTable.footer());

                                // If there are more than one footer rows
                                if ($footerRows.length > 1) {
                                    // First header row is already present, so we start from the second row (i = 1)
                                    for (let i = 1; i < $footerRows.length; i++) {
                                        // Get the current footer row
                                        let $footerRow = $footerRows[i];

                                        // Get footer row columns
                                        let $footerRowCols = $('th', $footerRow);

                                        // Increment the last row index
                                        footerIndex++;

                                        // Create the new header row XML using footerIndex and append it at sheetData
                                        $('sheetData', sheet).append(`
                                                    <row r="${footerIndex}">
                                                      ${$footerRowCols.map((index, el) => `
                                                        <c t="inlineStr" r="${String.fromCharCode(65 + index)}${footerIndex}" s="2">
                                                          <is>
                                                            <t xml:space="preserve">${$(el).text()}</t>
                                                          </is>
                                                        </c>
                                                      `).get().join('')}
                                                    </row>
                                                  `);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "processing": true,
                    data: data.teacherAttendanceReport,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            title: 'شماره', render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                            }
                        },
                        {title: 'نام کارمند', data: 'first_name'},
                        {title: 'روز هفته', data: 'persian_name'},
                        {title: 'ماه', data: 'month_name'},
                        {title: 'تاریخ مکمل', data: 'date'},
                        {title: 'ساعت درسی', data: 'full_time'},
                        {title: 'حالت حاضری', data: 'as_persian_name'},

                    ],


                });
                $(".h_report_icon").removeClass('fa fa-spinner fa-spin');
                $('#h_present').html(data.present)
                $('#h_absent').html(data.absent)


            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    });
```

When I take export as an `EXCEL` file, if the date is like `1400-2-15` the result is as expected. but if the date is like `1400-02-13` then it gets export like `######`.

I want it to be like `1400-02-13`, If anyone knows where is the problem, please help me!

Comment: The line `return moment(data, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD')` does nothing. you are expecting a date in format `YYYY-MM-DD` and you are formatting it in the same format. The problem could be something like the data is not in `YYYY-MM-DD` in the first place so moment can't parse it, or the date column is not the 3th column. If your table is exactly like the photo then it is not the 3th column.

Comment: @PouriaMoosavi So how can I do that?

Comment: @Zia Yamin, Did you try increasing the Width of the Column in Excel File where the date is exported to? Excel will show `######` when the Column width is unable to display the full date or numbers. And Don't forget to vote for Solutions that worked for you...

Comment: @Raky yes I did, as much as i increase the column, the number of ``########`` become more.

Answer (score -1):

Insert utf-8 meta tag in HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

or

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```